# compare a new value against previous value

Tags: mysql

I would like to be able to compare a newly inserted value against a previous value having the same id, and display the difference is the percentage of change.

Example:

```
id | bline_id |  avg   |    date

1  |     1    | 36.500 | 2013-03-28 11:08:10

31 |     1    | 37.130 | 2013-03-29 10:37:11
```

So what I'm looking for is 37.130-36.5/36.5 * 100 = 1.73% change

Comment: What you tried so far ? Can you show us your tried code ?

Comment: how many bline_id there? two or more?

Comment: you've used the php tag, so you expect a php solution?

Comment: @Akam there are a total of 30 bline_id.

Comment: @didierc I wasn't sure if this was better/easier to do at the mysql end or on the php end so I am open to both.

Comment: @Rikesh SELECT * FROM bl bl LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM blavg WHERE bline_id BETWEEN 1 and 30 ORDER BY id) blavg ON ( bl.bl_id = blavg.bline_id )WHERE bl.bl_id ORDER BY bl.bl_id ASC

Comment: is there always only 2 rows per distinct bline_id?

Comment: Yes didiec. The bline_id are numbered 1-30, and when you compare the previous to the new you have 2 per bline_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g.:

```
SELECT a.*
     , ROUND(((a.avg-b.avg)/b.avg)*100,2) pct_change
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM test x 
         JOIN test y 
           ON y.bline_id = x.bline_id 
          AND y.id >= x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM test x 
         JOIN test y 
           ON y.bline_id = x.bline_id 
          AND y.id >= x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) b
    ON b.bline_id = a.bline_id
   AND b.rank = a.rank+1
 WHERE a.rank = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a *self-join* on the MySQL table you'll be able to calculate all possible combinations of changes, in order to avoid duplicates you'll need a greater than/smaller than [not gt/lt or equal]. The below code should give some hints on how to construct such a query, although it is not tested and might contain an error or two.

```
SELECT ((larger.avg - smaller.avg) / (smaller.avg * 100)) AS change 
  FROM `table` AS smaller JOIN `table` AS larger 
  WHERE larger.id > smaller.id AND larger.bline_id = smaller.bline_id;
```